# Show "parent" form in a normal state

Tags: .net, winforms

When I perform this code:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
_fullscreenForm.Show();
_fullscreenForm.Focus();
```

I get the current window minimized and the `_fullscreenForm` is created minimized as well. How am I supposed to show it in normal state?

**UPDATE**:

Obviously I have tried to add `_fullscreenForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` and that doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**:

No, we cannot change the order of minimizing current form and appearance of another one, because there will be some work between those lines, so we literally need to:

1. Hide current form
2. Do some work
3. Show another form with results

**ANSWER**:

The form appeared behind the VS window, so we need to `Activate()` it.

Comment: Can you post on what event this is supposed to happen. What is the relationship between `this` and `_fullscreenForm`. Also have you tried to set the `_fullscreenForm.WindowState` property to `FormWindowState.Normal` ?? What do you get and what do you *want* to get.

Comment: @ja72: uhm, event? I need the `_fullscreenForm` to be shown after my code is called. I get the `_fullscreenForm` minimized (as I said in my Q). "What is the relationship between this and _fullscreenForm" --- how is it important? `_fullscreenForm` is just a private property of current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try showing `_fullscreenForm` before minimizing the current form.

```
_fullscreenForm.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
_fullscreenForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
_fullscreenForm.Focus();
```

EDIT:

with your original code, try

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
_fullscreenForm.Show();
_fullscreenForm.TopMost = true;
_fullscreenForm.Focus();
```

Comment: This code gives us another workflow: *show* - *hide*. But I need it strictly in the order I have described: 1) We hide the form 2) We do some useful work 3) We show another form with results.

Comment: @zerkms when you run your original code, `_fullscreenForm` is displayed normally after current form is minimized but if you have visual studion running, the form is behind it. Try minimizing VS before you try it.

Comment: I've chosen `Activate()`. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because windows load new windows from minimized programs also minimized. So just set `WindowState` of `_fullscreenForm` to `Maximized` or `Normal`, right after `Show()`

Comment: I don't need it *maximized*, I need it in its normal size.

Comment: Then i believe you are opening this as a child form, and then cant maximize it alone. You have to detach it from the main form.

Comment: what is "child form"? I can bring it back to the screen with mouse, clicking at task bar.